# Can I leave the Montreal Pierre Elliott Trudeau if I am an EU citizen?

Tags: eu-citizens, montreal

I have 16h overlay in Montreal and was wondering if I can leave the airport. I am an EU citizen.

Thanks in advance,
Malina